# People Like this button - dynamic counter increase when clicked

Tags: java, php, jquery

I need to create a button that says 3 people like this and when clicked it goes to 4 etc.. See this example it is perfect, but only for WordPress. Any suggestions? Ideas?

Thank you.

http://rosepritchard.ca/themeTests/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a plugin for WordPress called "[I Like This](http://lifeasrose.ca/2011/03/wordpress-plugin-i-like-this/)". The PHP is reasonably straight forward and it's just a matter of changing the WordPress hooks to integrate it with a different CMS.

Comment: Buit what about if you don't use WP. What alternatives are there?

Comment: @user718359: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the question. I thought you were looking for that specific WordPress plugin.

Comment: No problems. Thanks anyway for info. Still looking fro a non WP solution.